# Change location and new tab JQuery

Tags: jquery

Good day. I want to ask how do I change the location the parent page and It has a new tab appear. I tried it but the parent page does not changing the location. anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<form action="sell_pdf.php" method="POST" target="_blank" id="yourform">
<input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
<input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Submit" />
</form>


<script>
 $(function() { 
  $('#yourform').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(parseFloat($('#text1').val().replace(/,/g, '')) > parseFloat($('#text2').val().replace(/,/g, ''))) {
        $.post(
                $(this).attr('action')
                , $("form").attr('target', '_blank');
                , $(this).serialize()
                , function() { 

                    window.location.href = 'car_reserve.php';

                } );

    } else {
        alert('Actual price is less than selling price.');
    }
   } );
} );
```

Comment: $('#text1') and $('#text2') don't exist. The input's don't have an ID.

Comment: oh.. sorry.. I forgot.

Comment: @PedroEstrada I want to change the location of my parent page and at same time the new tab appears for my action in form.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: someone edited my question. sorry